# Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the regular expression to work (using jQuery) for a specific pattern I need.

I need following pattern:

First two character

- s of the string need to be numbers (0-9) but maximum number is 53. for numbers below 10 a leading 0 is required
- Character on position 3 needs to be a `.`
- the next 4 characters need to be a number between 0-9, minimum number should be 2010, maximum 2050

so, Strings like `01.2020`, `21.2020`, or `45.2020` have to match but `54.2020` or `04.2051` must not.

I tried to write the regex without the min and max requirement first and I'm testing the string using regex101.com but I'm unable to get it to work.

acording to the definition `/^[0-9]{2}\.\d[0-9]{4}$/` should allow me to insert the strings in the format `NN.NNNN`.

thankful for any input.

Comment: Why do you write \d and [0-9]? They are essentially identical (unless you also require non-ASCII digits, in which case you require \d). Most regexes have an analysis option. If you used this option you would see where your regex is incorrect. 
In particular, you coded:
match 2 digits, match period, match 1 digit and 4 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 numbers from 00 to 53 can be matched using this : `(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-3])` (00 -> 49 or 50 -> 53)

Character on position 3 needs to be a . : you've already got the `\.`

a number between 2010 and 2050 -> `20(?:[1-4][0-9]|50)` (20 followed by either 10 -> 49 or 50)

This gives :

```
(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-3])\.20(?:[1-4][0-9]|50)
```

Comment: thank you very much. aparently my toughts were all over the place.